# Macro that allows assignment or exists the current function

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to be able to realize:

```
#define GET_VALUE_OR_RETURN(value, expect) do { if (expect.valid()) \
        { value = move(expect.get()); } else return expect.get_error();break;} while(0)
```

expect is a class instance that has the members used in the macro. What I do is return from current function if valid() is false otherwise retrieve the value.

By using defined macro I have this usage syntax:

```
auto expect = CreateInstance(someData);
ResultType result;
GET_EXPECTED_VALUE_OR_RETURN(result, expect);
```

The disadvantage using this syntax is that I have to default initialize ResultType before using the macro and also use 2 lines of code only to be able to initialize my variable with a valid value. Is there something better ?

Comment: So you just want to remove the `ResultType result;` line? why don't you use templates? it's c++ after all. `#define GET_VALUE_OR_RETURN(Type, expect) do {Type value; if (expect.valid()) \
        { value = move(expect.get()); } else return expect.get_error();break;} while(0)` -> `GET_EXPECTED_VALUE_OR_RETURN(ResultType, expect)` but then you can't use value.

Comment: @moffeltje yes, haven't you seen it before? This would allow a semicolon after the macro like function call.

Comment: @iharob That's rather pointless: `value` is born and dies all inside of the macro, and can't be used in any surrounding code.

Comment: @moffeltje mostly for ensuring that you put ";" after the macro invocation from what I know (trigger compiler error)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just pointed that out in my comment - edited.

Comment: @Gmt exactly so I don't understand your question...

Comment: I suppose you could have a function that you could use like `if (auto res = get_expected_value(CreateInstance(someData))) {return res.return_value;} /*use res.result*/`. Honestly, I would question that specific function, but maybe someone can make it better.

Comment: You can the problem is that you want your function to return on error. And also this _2 lines of code only to be able to initialize my variable with a valid value_, is not so bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to have the macro expand to more than one statement, here's a solution:

```
#define GET_VALUE_OR_RETURN(value, expect) \
  if (!(expect).valid()) return (expect).get_error(); \
  value = move((expect).get())
```

Use:

```
auto expect = CreateInstance(someData);
GET_VALUE_OR_RETURN(ResultType result, expect);
```

Given that you actually want the macro to declare a variable, using it "unprotected" in an `if`/`else` branch is unlikely; therefore, the missing `do`–`while` shouldn't really matter.

You could even take it a step further:

```
#define GET_VALUE_OR_RETURN(type, value, expect) \
  auto &&value ## SuffixToPreventNameConflicts = (expect); \
  if (!(value ## SuffixToPreventNameConflicts).valid()) return (value ## SuffixToPreventNameConflicts).get_error(); \
  type value = move((value ## SuffixToPreventNameConflicts).get())

// Used like

GET_VALUE_OR_RETURN(ResultType, result, CreateInstance(someData));
```

Or two steps further, by removing `type` from the parameters and using `auto` in the second declaration.

Note that `SuffixToPreventNameConflicts` is not meant as a placeholder; it can taken literally. Since the name of the variable is based on `value`, duplicity from uses of the macro itself cannot happen (as it would happen for the result variable anyway). The suffix only exists to prevent accidental clashes with other, unrelated variables in the same scope.

Comment: @Gmt I've added the info to the answer; I believe we can purge the comment thread.